# How to limit download speed with Go?

Tags: performance, download, go, throttling, rate

I'm currently developing a download server in Go. I need to limit the download speed of users to 100KB/s.

This was my code:

```
func serveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fileID := r.URL.Query().Get("fileID")
    if len(fileID) != 0 {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.txt")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
        w.Header().Set("Content-Length", r.Header.Get("Content-Length"))

        file, err := os.Open(fmt.Sprintf("../../bin/files/test.txt"))
        defer file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        io.Copy(w, file)
    } else {
        io.WriteString(w, "Invalid request.")
    }
}
```

Then I found a package on github and my code became the following:

```
func serveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fileID := r.URL.Query().Get("fileID")
    if len(fileID) != 0 {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Wiki.png")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
        w.Header().Set("Content-Length", r.Header.Get("Content-Length"))

        file, err := os.Open(fmt.Sprintf("../../bin/files/test.txt"))
        defer file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        bucket := ratelimit.NewBucketWithRate(100*1024, 100*1024)
        reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
        io.Copy(w, ratelimit.Reader(reader, bucket))
    } else {
        io.WriteString(w, "Invalid request.")
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Corrupted Content Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in
>   the data transmission was detected.

Here's my code on the Go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/ulgXQl4eQO

Comment: I don't know that package, but I'd limit the writer, not the reader. Also, the Content-Type and Content-Length headers should not be copied from the request but set by the file type and file length. also also, you're reading a text file and writing it as png.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer it is https://github.com/juju/ratelimit, although I prefer https://github.com/aybabtme/iocontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing the error, but I did notice some issues with the code. For this:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
```

You should use the [mime package](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/)'s:

```
func TypeByExtension(ext string) string
```

To determine the content type. (if you end up with the empty string default to `application/octet-stream`)

For:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", r.Header.Get("Content-Length"))
```

You need to get the content length from the file itself. By using the request content length, for a `GET` this basically ends up as a no-op, but for a `POST` you're sending back the wrong length, which might explain the error you're seeing. After you open the file, do this:

```
fi, err := file.Stat()
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    return
}
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprint(fi.Size()))
```

One final thing, when you open the file, if there's an error, you don't need to close the file handle. Do it like this instead:

```
file, err := os.Open(...)
if err != nil {
    http.NotFound(w, r)
    return
}
defer file.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than mucking around with getting the correct the content type and length headers yourself it'd probably be much better to use [`http.ServeContent`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent) which will do that for you (as well as support "If-Modified-Since", range requests, etc. If you can supply an "ETag" header it can also handle "If-Range" and "If-None-Match" requests as well).

As mentioned previously, it's often preferable to limit on the write side but it's awkward to wrap an `http.ResponseWriter` since various http functions also check for optional interfaces such as `http.Flusher` and `http.Hijacker`. It's much easier to wrap the `io.ReadSeeker` that `ServeContent` needs.

For example, something like this perhaps:

```
func pathFromID(fileID string) string {
    // replace with whatever logic you need
    return "../../bin/files/test.txt"
}

// or more verbosely you could call this a "limitedReadSeeker"
type lrs struct {
    io.ReadSeeker
    // This reader must not buffer but just do something simple
    // while passing through Read calls to the ReadSeeker
    r io.Reader
}

func (r lrs) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return r.r.Read(p)
}

func newLRS(r io.ReadSeeker, bucket *ratelimit.Bucket) io.ReadSeeker {
    // Here we know/expect that a ratelimit.Reader does nothing
    // to the Read calls other than add delays so it won't break
    // any io.Seeker calls.
    return lrs{r, ratelimit.Reader(r, bucket)}
}

func serveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fileID := req.URL.Query().Get("fileID")
    if len(fileID) == 0 {
        http.Error(w, "invalid request", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    path := pathFromID(fileID)
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        http.NotFound(w, req)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fi, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "blah", 500) // XXX fixme
        return
    }

    const (
        rate     = 100 << 10
        capacity = 100 << 10
    )
    // Normally we'd prefer to limit the writer but it's awkward to wrap
    // an http.ResponseWriter since it may optionally also implement
    // http.Flusher, or http.Hijacker.
    bucket := ratelimit.NewBucketWithRate(rate, capacity)
    lr := newLRS(file, bucket)
    http.ServeContent(w, req, path, fi.ModTime(), lr)
}
```

Comment: What newLRS is? EDIT: found ;)

Comment: BTW, these days I'd prefer using [`golang.org/x/time/rate`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate) over `github.com/juju/ratelimit`.